# making a label element visible and setting its value in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have some javascript driving Google Maps API on an aspx page.

I'm performing some geocoding and I want to give the user feedback if we cannot find their search target but i seem unable to set a the message in the label

```
        <label id="msgFeedback" runat="server" class="message">[message to user]</label><br />
```

on init

```
document.getElementById('<%=msgFeedback.ClientID %>').style.display = 'none';
```

on unsuccessfuly geocoding

```
                document.getElementById('<%=msgFeedback.ClientID %>').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('<%=msgFeedback.ClientID %>').value = "Unable to locate the given resort";
```

I'm successfully displaying the label but it won't take the message.
All I'm getting is :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a label, it doesn't have a value, it has HTML content

```
document.getElementById('<%=msgFeedback.ClientID %>').innerHTML = "Unable to locate the given resort";
```